# How can I read text from a textfile without retrieving � for characters like 'ß' or 'ä'?

Tags: string, blueprism, rpa

When I am using the VBO Utility - File Management, it is very easy to get text from a textfile.
Unfortunately it returns � for characters like 'ß', 'ü' or 'ä'. So how can I eliminate � and get the correct characters?

Comment: Which RPA tool are you using?

Comment: Hello, I am using blueprism

Comment: So, since Automation Anywhere and UiPath are not related, please don't mention it. 
I just edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

The file that you're probably working on is using different than standard encoding. To read it, you need to improve the VBO, so that you'll be able to specify it.

Below you can find the code I am using.

```
Try
   If File.Exists(File_Name) Then
    if Encoding_Type = "" then
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(File_Name)
        Text = sr.ReadToEnd
        sr.Close()
    else
        Dim sr2 As New StreamReader(File_Name,Encoding.GetEncoding(CInt(Encoding_Type)))
        Text = sr2.ReadToEnd
        sr2.Close()
    end if
    Success = True
    Message = ""
   Else
      Throw New ApplicationException("The file at " & File_Name & " does not exist")
   End If
Catch e As Exception
    Success = False
    Message = e.Message
End Try
```

For german letters it should probably be encoding 28591.

You can read more about encodings at this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=netframework-4.7.2